# Parse REST response message using retrofit and observable

Tags: java, json, rest, observable, retrofit2

My API returns this when I use wrong login information (using postman):

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 401,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "login failed",
        "code": "LOGIN_FAILED",
        "stack": "Error: login failed\n    at ...path..."
    }
}
```

I am using this method to get the response message:

```
private void handleResponse(retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                emailField.setText(null);
                passwordField.setText(null);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                try {
                    showSnackBarMessage(response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showSnackBarMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
}
```

And the output (what snackbar shows) is the same as postman returns.

`handleresponse` parameter `retrofit2.Response<Response> response` consists of `retrofit2 Response`, and my own `<Response>` class which looks like this:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

How can I get only `message` to show in `snackbar`?

I have tried the following code, but I get only `No value for message`.

```
try {
     JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
     Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your json the response error body is an object with a field `error` which contains a field `message`. This means you first need to get the error object and then the message:

```
JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string()).getJSONObject("error");
Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Okay, this works. And just to be sure, is this a good way how to do it? I have seen many other methods, but none of them worked for me, but I guess it depends of the json I get, right?

Comment: To be honest I find this way a bit manual and therefore error prone. Since you're using `gson` you can always have it deserialize the error bodies for you too. But in the end, I wouldn't say this is wrong. It's just another way of doing things.

Comment: Because I am using Loopback framework for my api and I just couldn't get the messages...very complex framework..